# How to render a server response in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m trying to get data from server and than after some parsing, render it inside of a table in the component. But the problem is that the response from server is too late and my table is not shown.
How can i sync my data from server and the template ?

Thanks

```
class TFSBuilds extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            builds: []

        };

    }
      componentDidMount() {

         AzureService.send("ObCloud").then((data)=>{
             let groupedData = this.groupBy(data.value, obj => obj.definition.id)
             this.createChartObjects(groupedData)    
         });
    }

     createChartObjects(groupedRecords) {
        const arr = [];
        for (let [k, v] of groupedRecords) {
            if(v && k){

                 this.state.builds.push(v[0]);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    render() {
        const { builds } = this.state
        if (builds.length <= 0) { return null }
        return (
            <div className = "build-status" >
                <table className="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">By</th>
                        <th scope="col">When</th>
                        <th scope="col">Status</th>

                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {
                       builds.map(el =>
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{el.requestedBy.displayName}</th>
                            <td>{el.requestedBy.date}</td>
                            <td>{el.requestedBy.status}</td>
                        </tr>)
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default TFSBuilds;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setState` for your component to show changes. `this.state.builds.push(v[0]);` will not trigger an update of the component. Even just `setState(this.state)` after `this.createChartObjects(groupedData)` should work.

Also your function `createChartObjects` is returning an empty array, it could return an array of chartObjects you want to push into your state.

```js
const chartObjects = this.createChartObjects(groupedData);
this.setState({
  builds: this.state.builds.concat(chartObjects)
});
```

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user interface in response to event handlers and server responses.

@Src https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you're not triggering another render after state has been updated.  You can do this by calling setState() to change the state, rather than mutating the state object.

All you need to do is change this:

```
this.state.builds.push(v[0]);
```

to this:

```
this.setState({ builds: this.state.builds.concat(v[0]) });
```